# How to Set Application Shutdown Mode in a C# Windows Forms Project?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have just switched from VB.Net to C# and am writing a windows application.
In VB.net you could easily change the Shutdown Mode by selecting the properties of the 
project and moving to a dropdown where you could choose between "When startup form closes"
and "When last form closes". Please help me to find the equivalent in C#.

By the way, I'm using VS 2010.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In c# the easiest trick to achieve this is to change the entry point of the application in the "program.cs" file.
This entry form should be hidden on startup,but will call the main form. Then call the Application.Exit(); function in the close procedure in any other form/class.

Sample pseudo code below

program.cs

```
//edit this line
Applcation.Run(startupForm);
```

StratupForm.cs

```
//startup method
StartupForm_load (object e)
{
this.Hide();
MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
mainForm.show();
}
```

MainForm.cs

```
 //application exit method
    MainFormExit_close (object e)
    {
     Application.Exit();
    }
```

You should probably implement a neater way to manage and keep track of open forms later in your program

Comment: Your proposed "solution" is the definition of a memory leak.  You do not want to willingly and knowingly leave a form and all of its contents resident as a "trick".  You solved someone's problem with a new problem.  This is not a solution that should be approved on SO.

Answer (score 4):

It's not the first thing you might look for, but if you look at the docs for [Application.Run(ApplicationContext)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157901.aspx), you'll find sample code to do exactly what you're asking for: exit the application when the last form is closed.